# bug in add remove class with if else

Tags: jquery, html

Here is my Javascript code

```
$('.lable_item').click(function () {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('label_act')) {
        $(this).addClass('label_act');
    } else {
        $(this).removeClass('label_act');
    }
});
```

Here is my HTML Content

```
<div class="layout">
   <label class="lable_item"><input type="checkbox" />label</label>
   <label class="lable_item label_act"><input type="checkbox" />label</label>
   <label class="lable_item"><input type="checkbox" />label</label>
</div>
```

I want to add/remove class on lable tag. If label has "label_act", then it will be remove otherwise add class "label_act"

Comment: And what is the bug ?

Comment: Ok. What kind of bug do you have? Do you get errors in the console? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: use this code

    $('.lable_item').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass('.label_act ');
    });

Comment: The clearer the question, the easier it is for us to help you. Keep in mind that we didn't watch you develop the code, so we have no idea what it is intended to do. If it doesn't work as expected, you have to tell us **what** it is supposed to do and what behavior you currently observe.

Comment: @palaѕн click on the text and on the input more times and it will `"bug out"`

Comment: @Spokey: Oh great! we finally found `"THE BUG"`.

Comment: @palaѕн Except I found it in the first 3 seconds, but I guess no one here actually tries the code once to see the problem. They just comment

Comment: @Spokey: On a happy note, your answer got excepted. Cheers!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order for it not to run 2 times when you click you have to use the `input` instead of `label`

```
  $('.layout input').click(function () {
      $(this).parent().toggleClass('label_act')
  });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Spokey/Zf6bu/)

Answer (score 3):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xyPMN/)

```
$('.lable_item').find(':checkbox').on('change',function () {
    var $label = $(this).closest('label');
    $label.toggleClass('label_act',this.checked)
});
```